# A possible Resharper Bug or am I just missing something subtle?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, resharper-8.0

Here you can see how ReSharper is suggesting a change

[image]

Now here you can see how Resharper is changing up the code but the result is not correct because it is newing up a class, assigning a value to a property on it and then returning a totally new instance of that class that doesn't have the value assigned to it.

[image]

I had cursor on the new keyword. Pressed Alt+Enter and chose the option called "use object initializer".

Is this a possible bug in ReSharper or am I just missing something here?

Comment: What is it suggesting?

Comment: Yeah, that definitely doesn't look right.

Comment: That's wrong - it should refactor it to `return new FlightRetrievalResponse {test = "this is a test"};` - What is the exact version of R# is this?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen it is suggesting to use a object initializer and set the test property inside {}.

Comment: usually it suggest a class initializer

Comment: You sure you didn't pick "inline variable"?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen AH, that's a good thought.

Comment: It is exactly as vcsjones said. It should create the object by using the object initializer and return it!

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen no. I had cursor on the new keyword. Pressed Alt+enter and chose the option called "use object initializer".

Comment: Then yes, that looks like a bug. Which exact version of ReSharper are you using?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen I am using 8.2.1 thank you for your help I will go ahead and report it to JetBrains then. Just didn't want to look stupid after reporting so decided to check here first in case I was missing something.

Comment: If it is reproducible, I would try upgrading to 8.2.3, it may be a bug they've already fixed.

Comment: Not sure I was much of a help though, it sure looks like a bug, the end result is exactly what "inline variable" would produce, and if it appeared after you applied "Use object initializer" then something got crosswired in there. If I experienced this I would first upgrade, then I would try to create a reproducible and simple example, and then contact Jetbrains. They always answer rather promptly to support requests so I would definitely do that.

Comment: Though you should edit some more details into your question, like which quickfix you picked, etc. A question should be standalone and never rely on comments providing the missing details.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen makes sense will edit the comment to get it out there. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not looking correctly. 
It should look like:

```
return new FlightRetrievalResponese
{
   test = "this is a test"
};
```

What is your R# version?